# AJAX data not sent to the PHP file

Tags: php, ajax, ajax-request

I have a problem in my AJAX . My javascript file is unable to send data to the PHP file. My javascript file :

```
function updateTile(tile_no){

    var ajaxRequest;

    var color = document.getElementById("color_"+tile_no).value;
    //alert($color);
    var img_path = document.getElementById("url_"+tile_no).value;
    //alert(url);
    var title = document.getElementById("title_"+tile_no).value;

    try{

    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){

        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){

                alert("Browser Error !");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){


            document.getElementById("box_tile"+tile_no).innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("box_tile"+tile_no).innerHTML = '<img src=ajax-loader.gif /> <br /> ';
        }
    }

    var url = "update.php?color="+color+"&url="+img_path+"&img_path="+title;

    alert(url);

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

The `alert(url);` shows `update.php?color=#444444&url=http://somesite/image.jpg&img_path=Tile 1`. My `update.php` file :

```
<?php


    $color_code = $_GET['color'];

    $img_url = $_GET['img_path'];

    $title = $_GET['title'];

    echo 'Color Code :'.$color_code;
    echo '<br />Image Path :'.$img_url;
    echo '<br />Title :'.$title;

/*
echo '<div style="background:'.$color_code.';width:100%;height:100%;vertical-align:bottom;color:#f8f8f8;font-family:Trebuchet MS;"><img src="'.$img_url.'" /><span>'.$title.'</span></div>';
*/  
?>
```

But the response from the PHP shows empty results !

```
Color Code :
Image Path :
Title :
```

Comment: Use url encoding for sending `GET` data. Or else use `POST` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode the image path as it is a url and the colour as it contains a `#` (use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent))

Your query string seems all messed up, you pass `color`, `url` and `img_path` but expect  `color`, `img_path` and `title`

Also

```
var url = "update.php?color="+encodeURIComponent(color)+
          "&img_path="+encodeURIComponent(img_path)+"&title="+title;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the hash symbol in your colour variable is throwing it off.

Forget AJAX, go to your update.php directly with the above get variables and do a print_r($_GET) and you'll see that nothing is being passed into the $_GET variable.

Get rid of the hash and you're golden

That is to say, send the hex color code without the hash (#)

update.php?color=444444 instead of update.php?color=#444444

Comment: Yes..you are right HighParkCoder.. Why this hash symbol is not allowing to send data? Thanks .

Comment: Anything after a hash is ignored.  It's also not necessary in your case.

Comment: Also disregard the comment below to interchange $_REQUEST with $_GET.  That is bad advice.  $_REQUEST will also return cookie variables which can really mess things up if you have a cookie variable that shares the same namespace as a $_GET variable and it will overwrite it.  I learned that lesson the hard way!  Very frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Try post method because as u might know url has some limitation over passing character while post can send as much data as u want.

And one more thing try to use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET` see either will work.